# Convert a flattened single row into multiple rows Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database table that has essentially flattened a 'poll question' dimension into the table with 1 column for each question.

For example: these are the columns in the table:

```
POLL1_QUESTION
POLL1_ANSWER

POLL2_QUESTION
POLL2_ANSWER

POLL3_QUESTION
POLL3_ANSWER
```

What I want to do is map each row into a new table like this:

```
QUESTION_NUMBER
QUESTION
ANSWER
```

The question number column isn't even necessary in my use case, but it would be nice.

Is it possible to convert this 1 row with 6 columns to instead 3 rows of 2 columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `UNPIVOT` if you are using Oracle database 11g or above:

```
select *
from your_table
unpivot (
    (question, answer) 
    for question_id in (
        (question1, answer1) as 1,
        (question2, answer2) as 2,
        (question3, answer3) as 3
        )
);
```

For prior to Oracle 11g, use `case` (or `decode`):

```
select
    n as question_id,
    case n
        when 1 then question1
        when 2 then question2
        when 3 then question3
    end as question,
    case n
        when 1 then answer1
        when 2 then answer2
        when 3 then answer3
    end as answer
from your_table
cross join (
    select level as n
    from dual
    connect by level <= 3
) x;
```